# EXTJS:How to paint a row in different color in TreeGrid based on the a property in Response?

Tags: javascript, extjs, tree

I am using treegrid to display the data.

Question: How to paint a row in a different color based on value of one of the column?

We may not be able to use row renderer which we normally use in normal grid. Can I use column render to paint the entire row from inside the column renderer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23664590/4969870 ?

Comment: Thanks Pawel. Thats the exact POST that gave me good pointers to find my solution. However, I am adding a new Answer as I faced a different issue as I am working with Sencha Architect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Painting the rows on the gridPanel can be done using viewConfig configuration on grid panel -

```
viewConfig: {
      getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store) {
                              return record.get('mycls');
                          }
}
```

However, I faced a strange issue while working with SenchaArchitect.
Tree Grid Panel by default has viewConfig property available but while I searched for this property to add my logic, Sencha Editor did not show it and I ended up by adding `viewConfig :{}` manually thru the Sencha architect. This leads to 2 viewConfigs in my grid panel instance (One with my implementation and the default one). So my viewConfig object is overridden by the default empty viewConfig object and my logic was never executed.

To overcome this issue, I had to keep a dirty heck and implemented this logic in the afterRender function as below.

```
Grid.getView().getRowClass = function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store){ 
    return record.get('mycls');
}
```

This is a potential bug in Sencha Architect.